# I can't remote ssh to my centos server

Tags: linux, ssh

I used to use set `ssh-key` for no password login for my `CentOS` server, but right now I have changed to new laptop, so I can't use `ssh` to my server.

**1** I used to set a port 2345 in my last machine `~/.ssh/config` file

```
Host mysite
HostName mysite.com
User william
Port 2345
```

Then i use `ssh mystic` to log in.

**2** 22 port refused.

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
port 22: Connection refused
```

**3**

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -p 2345
`Permission denied, please try again.`
```

Please. I am glad for any possible help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, as many suggest close this issue. I finally figure out is checked the `ssh_config` file and `sshd_config` file to make sure

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Hope can help someone.